# Есть переменная , есть ajax запрос который возвращает именно то что мне нужно. Как ответ передать в переменную?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: './getData',
    success: function(res) {
        console.log(res);
    }
});
```

console.log выводит:

```
[{"i":"7459","p":"0","r":"2759.65","d":102022},{"i":"0","p":"0","r":"0","d":112021}]
```

Когда вручную прописать в переменную, то все ок. Как мне передать в эту переменную результат запроса? Одним слово передать res

```
var data = [{"i":"7459","p":"0","r":"2759.65","d":102022},{"i":"0","p":"0","r":"0","d":112021}]
```

Вот например

`

```
var data;
    $.ajax({
          method: 'POST',
           url: './getData',
           success: function(res) {
                console.log(res);
                data = res;
           }
    });
```

`

Так не записывает

Comment: А где ваша переменная находится относительно данного вызова? И как происходит запрос, он в какой то функции или вызывается 1 раз?

Comment: При загрузке страницы. Находится в $(document).ready(function() {}

Comment: Вот например

   ` var data;
    $.ajax({
          method: 'POST',
           url: './reports/createDataForJs',
           data: {},
           success: function(res) {
                console.log(res);
             data = res;
           }
    });`

Так не записывает

Comment: Записывает, только данные из `data` берутся быстрее, чем успевает отработать `ajax` запрос и положить туда данные

Comment: И что можно сделать?

Comment: Посмотрите в шапке вашего вопроса или здесь [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1452819/](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1452819/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb-for-%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb-%d0%95%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86/1452820#1452820)

Comment: Как ни странно не срабатывает. Прочитал давно. делал так. Может что то не понимаю? <pre>function getResult(callback) {
      $.ajax({
          method: 'POST',
           url: './getData',
           success: function(res) {
                callback(res);
           }
    });
}

getResult(function(result) {
  data = result;
})
</pre>

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139752/discussion-between-i-zrchnsk-and-swad).